# D3.js: Joining json and csv not working

Tags: javascript, json, csv, d3.js

I want to create a map with the static map in a json file and the dynamic data in a csv file. The map displays but the dynamic data from the cvs file is not working. I've attempted to follow mbostock's explanations but so far I can't get the join to work. Here is the code:

```
d3.json("/sites/default/d3_files/json/toronto-wards.json", function(error,wards) {
   var csvData;
d3.csv("/csv-pledges", function(error, csv) 
{
    csvData = csv;

   alert ("Hello" +csvData); // this displays

joinJsonCsv(csvData);
   alert ("Bye"); // doesn't display 
}); // end d3.csv

function joinJsonCsv(csv) {
// do something with rows
  alert ("joinJsonCsv" +csv); // this displays
   csv.forEach(function(d, i) {
     alert("the value of e.SCODE_NAME is: "+e.SCODE_NAME); // doesn't display
        world.forEach(function(e, j) {
            if (d.ward_no === e.SCODE_NAME) 
            {  
                e.NAME = d.ward_no
            } // end ward test
        }) // end world loop loop
    })// end of csv loop
alert ("exit joinJsonCsv"); // this doesn't display
} // end joinJsonCsv
```

What am I missing?

Comment: That is a good question but I have to confess that I do  not know. I am not an expert javascript (or d3) programmer so I copied the join code from an example (I think) prepared by mbostock without understanding what e (or for that matter d) really refer to. I'd appreciate some info that would explain this.

Comment: Can you post your json and csv data too?

Answer (score 1):

You were referencing the `e` object outside of its scope so the function was crashing. I moved the alert so that `e` is defined, it should work now.
    d3.json("/sites/default/d3_files/json/toronto-wards.json", function(error,wards) {
       var csvData;
    d3.csv("/csv-pledges", function(error, csv) 
    {
        csvData = csv;

```
   alert ("Hello" +csvData); // this displays

joinJsonCsv(csvData);
   alert ("Bye"); // doesn't display 
}); // end d3.csv

function joinJsonCsv(csv) {
// do something with rows
  alert ("joinJsonCsv" +csv); // this displays
   csv.forEach(function(d, i) {
        world.forEach(function(e, j) {
            alert("the value of e.SCODE_NAME is: "+e.SCODE_NAME); // try this maybe
            if (d.ward_no === e.SCODE_NAME) 
            {  
                e.NAME = d.ward_no
            } // end ward test
        }) // end world loop loop
    })// end of csv loop
alert ("exit joinJsonCsv"); // this doesn't display
} // end joinJsonCsv
```

Comment: I don't think I can post large files here but the json data is at http://stopplastics.ca//sites/default/d3_files/json/toronto-wards.json and the csv data at http://stopplastics.ca//csv-pledges (although at this point it is just test data.) and the map is at http://www.stopplastics.ca/clone-toronto-ward-map

Comment: I've managed to get the join to work (there were several errors) but it reverts to the original values once it is out of the loop. I had hoped that the join would last for the entire json block but not. I'll have to find out why.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I got it working ... I moved the remaining code into the joinJsonCsv function and it works.